# UICollectionViewController would show me a wrong image for a moment and then refresh to the right one

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating a collection view from a JSON response. The Json response has high res images and the number of images in around 2000. Since the data is from a 3rd party i don't have control on the image size.

Implementation:

JSON Sample:

```
{
    "imagelist": [
        {
            "largeImage": "https://amazingphotos/01.jpg"
        },
        {
            "largeImage": "https://amazingphotos/02.jpg"
        },
}
```

Accessing the JSON in UICollectionViewController:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, dataURL)
            .responseJSON { _, _, result in
                if var json:JSON = JSON(result.value!){
                self.imageURLs = json["imagelist"].arrayValue
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
        }
```

In cellForItemAtIndexPath, i am passing the URLs to the cell rather than the image itself.

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.imageData = imageURLs[indexPath.row]
```

And in custom Cell i am just doing this:

```
var imageData:SwiftyJSON.JSON?{
        didSet{
            self.setup() 
        }
    }

    func setup(){
        if let imageURLString = self.imageData?["largeImage"]{
            let imageURL = NSURL(string: imageURLString.stringValue)
            self.imageThumbnail.hnk_setImageFromURL(imageURL!)
        }
```

ISSUE: When i load the collection view it shows the images properly, as soon as i start scrolling it shows me previous images on new cells for couple of seconds and then gets refreshed.

I have used collection view multiple times but never worked with so much data. Please advice.
TIA

Comment: nil out the imageView's image in `prepareForReuse`

Comment: Hi Chris, this solution has worked. Thanks. Would you mind putting your comment as an answer and i can mark it as solved. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing as you scroll your collection view is a reused cell which contains the image from the previous use. `UICollectionViewCell` has a `prepareForReuse` function that you can use to set any subviews back to a default state.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {

    myImageView.image = nil

    super.prepareForReuse()
}
```

Comment: dude you're a legend

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Its generally not a good practice to pass the image URL instead of image to a cell, if you haven't implemented caching.
You can try fixing this by one of the following approaches:

1. `nil` out the `imageView`'s image in `prepareForReuse` (as suggested
   by `ChrisH`)
2. Download images one-by-one and store them in an array.   Once an image is downloaded, call:
   `collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths);` for that
   particular cell.
3. Restructure your code and implement image caching.

If you need help in implementing image caching (using `NSCache`), following `Objective-C` code might give you an idea:

```
@interface MBGalleryViewController ()
{
    NSArray* imageUrls;  // array of image urls
    NSCache* cache;
}
@end

@implementation MBGalleryViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    cache = [[NSCache alloc] init]; // initialize cache
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [imageUrls count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* identifier = @"Cell";

    MyCollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier
                                                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {

        UIImage* image = [cache objectForKey:@(indexPath.item)];  // retrieve image for this indexPath.item
        if (!image) {  // will be true if is not yet cached
            image = [imageDownloader downloadImageWithURL:imageUrls[indexPath.item]];  // download image from somewhere
            [cache setObject:image forKey:@(indexPath.item)];   // cache image for this indexPath.item
        }

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            cell.imageView.image = image;  // set image
        });
    });

    return cell;
}

@end
```

**Original Post**
I also faced a similar issue in past.
This is either because the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is getting called before the image has actually been downloaded or maybe due to image not getting updated on main queue.
The workaround to this problem is to set a default image for your `ImageView` in `UICollectionViewCell`.
Also try setting the image like this:
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    cell.imageView.image = imageURLs[indexPath.row];
}`
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I had a default image already and it would show up only for certain cells and not all during scrolling. Others would have old images. I tried the dispatch_async option now but didn't helped. :(